# I want to set a cell in Excel to show a typed in time and then each subsequent cell in that colum show a time 15 min later

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have one cell - where I type a time,  say 8:00am. Now in the next cell down in that same column I want the time to automatically add fifteen min.
So in column A it would look like this
Time:
8:00 AM (this I would type in, and the  rest would just show the next 15 min)
8:15 AM
8:30 AM
8:45 am
9:00 AM

Comment: This is pretty easy — even trivial. Have you done any research? What have you learned? What have you tried? What specific piece of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to write the time in cell `A1` and then column `A` going down should automatically add 15 mins.

You would put in `A2` the following:

```
=$A1+TIME(0,15,0)
```

And then pull down the formula to the whole column.

See animation:
[image]